# mv cannot stat '*.txt' : No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell

Be nice. I'm learning Linux and can't find this answer (I've searched)
I'm trying to move all the .txt files in Folder1 to my Documents directory.

```
~$ ls
Desktop Documents Downloads file1.txt Music Public Templates test user0files.txt user-files.txt Videos
~$ cd ~/Documents
~/Documents$ ls 
Folder1 Folder2 test1.txt test2.txt
~/Documents$ cd ~/Documents/Folder1
~/Documents/Folder1$ ls
bale.txt, ball.txt, bowl.txt, foldernew
~/Documents/Folder1$ mv *.txt ~/Documents
mv: cannot stat '*.txt': No such file or directory
```

From here I tried moving foldernew by name to ~/Documents and it worked. Can someone explain what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux questions should be posted to [unix.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: For checking the files, I suggest that you do a `ls -l` instead of a plain `ls` in this particular case. You will see better what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a bunch of files that end in `.txt,` (note the comma), so `*.txt` doesn't find them.

Rename the files to remove the comma and try again.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the * wildcard incorrectly. How can I use the * wildcard to move all my .txt files at the same time?

Comment: @user2390330 At some point you likely ran an incorrect command, maybe `touch bale.txt, ball,txt, ...` or `for file in bale.txt, ball.txt, ...`. The comma is not shell syntax and instead became part of the filename, so now they end in the four characters "tee ex tee comma" instead of the three letters "tee ex tee". You should rename `bale.txt,` to `bale.txt` (removing the comma) with `mv` or `rename`, and similar with the other files. Then it should work as expected.

Comment: This actually makes so much sense. thanks so much for your help!!!